# How to 'slideUp' remaining portion of the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a div which I am showing just a portion of the top using absolute positioning and hidden overflow. When you hover over I want to show the remaining portion of the div. This div could be different total height based on the info inside.

https://jsfiddle.net/5abs1ocf/4/

```
.showAll {
    bottom: 0px;
}

.showLittle {
    top: 265px;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(item).find('.info').toggleClass('showLittle showAll');
```

As you can see from [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/5abs1ocf/4/), I have it working where it "pops" from one to the other. What I really want is for it to animate and "slide" up and down rather than just "popping" from one to the other.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `top` property use a negative `bottom` value:

```
.showLittle {
    bottom: -105px;
}
```

And then use a transition:

```
.info {
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/5abs1ocf/1/)

An alternative way, if you want a dynamic height, is to use jQuery to calculate the offset:

```
    var elementHeight = -($('.info').height() - 34);
    console.log(elementHeight);
    $('.showLittle').css('bottom', elementHeight);
```

And set the following CSS:

```
.showAll {
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/5abs1ocf/2/)

Comment: One issue with this is that I will have multiple `.tree` boxes. I can't dynamically set the `bottom` value using jQuery as you described because the `bottom` value will need to be different for each of the `.tree` boxes. See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5abs1ocf/3/)

Comment: Ok, think I came up with a solution. See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5abs1ocf/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Javascript, just use CSS.

```
.info {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: -102px;
    transition: margin 0.5s ease;
}
.tree:hover .info {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```